# MSAL Authentication not working in Angular 17.0.5

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-ad-msal, angular17

I am implementing MSAL authentication in Angular 17.0.5 and unable to authenticate using AD credentials and its giving 401 Un-authorized error. Same code was working in Angular 11.2.12.

These are the dependencies of the application

```
Node: 18.16.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
"@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.0.2",
"@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^17.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
"minimatch": "^9.0.3",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.14.2"
```

1. I have tried changing msal version from *^3.6.0* to *^3.0.0-alpha.2*.
2. Added `system: { allowNativeBroker: false }`.

inside `PublicClientApplication` in `MSALInstanceFactory`.

Comment: Are you able to run the app locally?

Answer (score 0):

"@azure/msal-browser" is not compatible with Angular 17 yet. In order to use @azure libraries you need to downgrade angular to version 16.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/6719

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there's no resolution for it. The team responsible for MSAL development someone missed the profound change in how DI and service registration is handled in Angular 17. It seems that [their 1st line support agents aren't aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1465589/msal-package-issues) of it neither.

It's truely pathetic, given that MS aspires to be the numero uno choice for professional developers. It's not a reliable strategy, in my opinion.

For now, you have three options.

1. Downgrade, as suggested by Ze_eduardo's answer.
2. Apply a different framework, like React or Blazor.
3. Tamper with MSAL's internals yourself.

We tried to follow the last alternative and got it working for a while, only to realize that there were additional issues with other auth flows, some instability and weird cache behavior. FInally, we caved in and downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use MSAL with Angular 17. See below versions of Angular and MSAL along with other packages in package.json

```json
"@angular/animations": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.41",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.5",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.11",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.7.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
```

Also make sure to initialize using following line in your service constructor body where you use MSAL

```js
this.msalService.initialize();
```

Comment: Could you post a sample where you inject the MSAL service, please? The full file including the constructor that you refer to, not just the line with the method `initialize()`, that is.